# 3D two-variable function with constraint

Tags: plotting, functions

How can I plot 3d the function z (x,y)=x/4+  2y/2.3 with constraint (1+x/4.2)y^2= 3700

Comment: Have you tried `Plot3D` yet? You can use a `RegionFunction` , but your constraint will need to be an inequality instead of `=` or you won't see anything.

Comment: 'z[x,y]' is a function of 2 variables. However, if you request '(1+x/4.2)y^2= 3700', then e.g. x is a function of y: 'x[y]' and your original function is now: 'z[x[y],y]' a function of only one variable that can e.g. be plotted using ' Plot'. Or if you want a 3D plot: ' ParametricPlot3D'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Region[ParametricRegion[{{x, y, x/4 + (2 y)/2.3}, (1 + x/4.2) y^2 == 
    3700}, {{x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}}], 
 BaseStyle -> {Thick, Red}, Boxed -> True, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Or

```
Plot3D[x/4 + (2 y)/2.3, {x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}, 
 MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y}, (1 + x/4.2) y^2], Mesh -> {{3700}},
  MeshStyle -> {Thick, Red}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.1], 
 PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

Or

```
sol = Solve[(1 + x/4.2) y^2 == 3700, x];
ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, x/4 + (2 y)/2.3} /. sol[[1]], {y, -100, 100}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!